# Access denied if Call used along with MOVE in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax

Here is my Batch script

```
CALL jekyll build
MOVE _site E:\
MD temp
SET src_folder=E:\_site
SET tar_folder=.\temp

for /f %%a IN ('dir "%src_folder%" /b') do move %src_folder%\%%a %tar_folder%

pause
```

In this script if the jekyll build command is not used,all the move and make directory commands are working properly however if the CALL is added,the output is as shown

```
Configuration file: E:/Workspace/Github/rrevanth.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: E:/Workspace/Github/rrevanth.github.io
       Destination: E:/Workspace/Github/rrevanth.github.io/_site
      Generating...
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.10/lib/posix/spawn.rb:164: warning: cannot close fd before spawn
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
Access is denied.
A subdirectory or file temp already exists.
```

Here,it is showing that Access is denied.Is there any workaround or am I doing anything wrong here.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Use `echo on`. IMHO that `Access is denied.` error raised by `MOVE _site E:\ ` command as writing into a drive root could be restricted... Or `_site` folder could contain a file locked by `jekyll`

Comment: As an additional bit of investigation I found this post https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2789, which may be relevant to your issue... all the best.

Comment: The problem is that apparently an error is generated during the `CALL` operation (*'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command*), which may mean that there's an issue creating the directory you're trying to move. It's important to actually read the content of the error messages, because there is typically actual meaning to those words. It appears (from what you've posted here) that the "access denied" is an after-effect of the actual problem. The prior error is causing a later problem.

Comment: @KenWhite :I have actually deleted the destination folder so that no issue to create the folder.I ran the script with only move operations and everything is working fine that way so I assume we don't have any persmission issues too.The problem only arises when I call any other programs apart from inbuilt commands AFAIK.

Comment: @Chris : I have seen the issue.That is the error where jekyll and pygments compatibility problem for generating static sites.Although it throws an error,we can still generate the sites.My question is not related to that error.Please see my above comment. :)

Comment: @5ud0 Apologies for that, a cursory glance at that post gave me the impression the issue was related to moving the site, not serving it. I'm trawling through Jekyll [documentation](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/5-running-jekyll/), trying to get a better understanding of its mechanisms.

Comment: You missed my point. Apparently something is failing in the `CALL jekyl build` operation, where a *'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command* error is being generated. It seems to be somewhere in or after `spawn.rb:164`, which gives you a place to start looking (spawn.rb, line 164). Whatever is happening on that line is causing things after it to not work properly.

Comment: @Chris  : I think I might have commented the wrong way.Actually if I ran the commands as mentioned in batch script the way they are in normal cmd.they run fine.jekyll will throw the error but the site is created.My problem is as said in the question itself,it has nothing to do with jekyll.

Comment: @KenWhite : I am sorry if you misunderstood,but the which error it is throwing will occur even though it is called without CALL command.

Comment: I think *you're* still misunderstanding. The error you're seeing (related to "which" not being recognized) can only come from `jekyl build` somewhere), and the error message indicates it's coming from `spawn.rb`, which is certainly not used by `move` or `md`. But I'll leave the issue to you; there's no sense in repeating myself over and over again. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently attempting to use `move` to move a directory to a different drive fails with "Access is denied."  I'm able to recreate on my end, believe it or not.

> ```
> C:\Users\rojo\Desktop>md test
>
> C:\Users\rojo\Desktop>md d:\test
>
> C:\Users\rojo\Desktop>rd d:\test
>
> C:\Users\rojo\Desktop>move test d:\
> Access is denied.
> ```

Looks like you'll have to `xcopy srcdir dest` then `rd /q /s srcdir` to move instead.  You might need to add some switches to your `xcopy` command, depending on your situation -- for example, `/y` to overwrite existing; or `/h` to include hidden and system files.  See `xcopy /?` for details.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Was I incorrect either in my assessment of the situation or my advice to work around the problem?

Comment: move is working fine if only move commands are used in file.

My problem is whenever I am calling other programs.move is showing access denied